# Issues with setting up Comodo SSL with Gunicorn on Non 443 port

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate, postman

We use EliteSSL

On our server I have an nginx instance which was no issue to set up however using the X509Certificate only and server.key file.

However I also have 5 API endpoints served out through gunicorn on non standard ports.

It is impossible to get the cert to behave. Any client connecting...postman or python requests says that it an unverified cert...however the Nginx works fine. Is this a result of the non standard port?

> ```
> Error: unable to verify the first certificate
> ```

The only certificate which works is the X509CertOnly(verification off) and none of the other 8 sent work with the system..all give errors.

```
--certfile /usr/local/AA_CERTS/X509CertOnly/server_bc_edu_cert.cer --keyfile /usr/local/AA_CERTS/server.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your intermediate and root certificate with --ca-cert.

These are provided by your browsers but not by your guniocorn/flask installation.